# How to scale bezier handles to preserve curvature

Tags: curvature, bezier-curve

Given a cubic bezier path $P_0P_1 P_2 P_3$, when one handle is scaled how, to scale other handle to preserve same level of curvature at $P_0$?

I tried to find $\Delta$ of $P_1$ using a second derivative, but it changes angle of the handle.

Then I found a curvature function.
It is definitely possible to use the function to find  $\Delta$, but it’s hard to solve analytically.

Is there any other helpful curvature equations?

[Illustration of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOmyj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the curvature vector (not just curvature magnitude) at $P_0$ when moving $P_2$, you will need to preserve the vertical distance between $P_2$ and line $\overline{P_0P_1}$. This means that $P_2$ can only be moved in the direction of $\vec{P_0P_1}$.

Therefore, if you want to move $P_2$ in a direction that is perpendicular to $\overline{P_0P_1}$ (as shown in your picture), the only way to preserve curvature vector at $P_0$ is to move $P_0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ all together.

Comment: Thank you for the answer)

Now I can see the difference between a curvature vector and a curvature magnitude. 

Is using $k(t) = \frac{x''y' - x'y''}{(x''+y'')^{3/2}}$ is the only way to create a equation system, to preserve curvature magnitude?

Comment: That is the only formula for computing curvature magnitude that I am aware of.

Comment: @fang, Can we say that if we preserve the internal angles of the polygon formed by the control points, we preserve the curvature at every point ?

Comment: No. One counter example is to scale up the control polygon uniformly. The entire curve looks the same and internal angles of control polygon are preserved. However, the curvature magnitude will become smaller.